# Optimizing this code to check sum

Tags: c, algorithm

This is the problem, I'm trying to solve in SPOJ. I am getting time limit exceeded problem. I can't find a way to optimize the algorithm. Can you give me some tips.

Here is the problem:

> Leonard had to find the number of continuous sequence of numbers such
>   that their sum is zero.
>
> For example if the sequence is- 5, 2, -2, 5, -5, 9
>
> There are 3 such sequences
>
> 2, -2
>
> 5, -5
>
> 2, -2, 5, -5
>
> Since this is a golden opportunity for Leonard to rewrite the Roommate
>   Agreement and get rid of Sheldon's ridiculous clauses, he can't afford
>   to lose. So he turns to you for help. Don't let him down.
>
> Input
>
> First line contains T - number of test cases
>
> Second line contains n - the number of elements in a particular test
>   case.
>
> Next line contain n elements, ai  (1<=i<= n) separated by spaces.
>
> Output
>
> The number of such sequences whose sum if zero.
>
> Constraints
>
> 1<=t<=5
>
> 1<=n<=10^6
>
> -10<= ai <= 10

Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


main()
{
 int t, j, k, l, sum;
 long long int num, out = 0;
 long long int ai[1000001];
 scanf("%d",&t);

 while(t--)
 {
    for(j=0;j<=num;j++)
    {   
    scanf("%lld",&ai[j]);
    }
    for(l=0;l<=num;l++)
    {

        for(k=l; k<=num; k++)
        {
          if(sum == 0)
          {
            num++;
          }
          else
          {
            sum = sum + ai[k];
          }

        }
        printf("%d", &num);
    }

 }
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let S[i] be the sum of elements from index 0 to index i (prefix sum). Set S[-1] = 0.

You can observe that if a sequence from index i to index j (j > i) sums to 0, S[j] - S[i-1] = 0, or S[j] = S[i-1].

In order to solve this problem, just keep a mapping of the value of S[i] (i=**-1**..n-1) to the frequency of the sum. If a particular sum recurs k times, you can have k choose 2 ways to pairing up the indices to create distinct sequences. You can obtain the total number of sequences by summing up all the ways to pair up the indices, by going through all the keys and check the frequency at the end.

The implementation of the map should be at most *O(log n)* for insert and update operations. This will allow to you to solve the problem with overall complexity of *O(n log n)*: prefix sum *O(n)*, insert/update the map *O(n log n)*, going through the whole map to sum up the result *O(n)*.

Pseudocode:

```
a[n] // Array of elements

m = new Map[Int->Int] // Frequency mapping

s = 0 // Prefix sum

m[s] += 1

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  s += a[i] // Prefix sum of array of elements a
  m[s] += 1 // Increment frequency of the prefix sum by 1
}

out = 0

// Go through all key values in the map
m.traverse(function (key, value) {
    // Add the number of pairs of indices that has the same prefix sum
    out += value * (value - 1) / 2
})

return out
```

Comment: Thanks, But i was never into this frequency, mapping kind of programming before. But would that decrease the execution time, because you are also using loops in this and wouldn't that execute through same time?

Comment: @user3129609: Your program is doing triply nested loop, which looks like it will run in O(n^3). Pre-calculating prefix sum and brute force all pairs of indices will take O(n^2). Both above solution don't work since n is set to be 10^6. Even at O(n^2), the number of operations is on the order of 10^12, which is too much for a computer to handle in 1-3 sec. My algorithm uses loop, but it also uses data structure, which reduces the run time to O(n log n), which I think should be able to pass the run time limit with lots of time to spare.

Comment: @user3129609: Just in case, map is an abstract data structure. It can be implemented by a binary tree or hashing. I suggest that you read up some book on data structure and algorithm complexity analysis before continuing on, because it requires those knowledge to understand the approach and to code the solution.

Comment: There are some issues here, first is memory limitation, the solution only work when the memory is n*20. And actually the last 4 lines is not necessary, as at a specific index ,the number of sequence that ends in the index is the frequency of the sum (at this index). The complexity should be O(n)

Comment: @nhahtdh I have added my solution, the data structure can be array instead of a map :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it is similar to [nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh), but the time complexity is O(n)
Pseudocode:

```
        int pos[10000001];
        int neg[10000001];
        int sum = 0;
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            sum += arr[i];
            if(sum > 0){
                result += pos[sum];
                pos[sum]++;

            }else{
                result += neg[-sum];
                neg[-sum]++;
            }


        }
        return result;
```

Comment: @AlexReynolds I am sorry, but the syntax is so similar that I don't think the OP cannot understand, and he only ask for a hint, not a runnable solution, which I think this should be enough.

Comment: I forgot to look at the constraint on ai. The constraint on ai allows for this solution to be used, which is faster so +1. The array is basically a map, and you add the result on-the-fly, which is better than my approach. (Then again, there shouldn't be any memory problem with my solution, though).

Comment: I don't think you understand, so I will make it perfectly clear: The syntax you are using is **incorrect**.

Comment: Can you suggest any book or website to learn more about this kind of programming approach (maps, complexityO), i don't even know what that [] behind variable name even mean

Comment: @user3129609 sorry, that means array. You can read one of a very classic book about algorithm is "Introduction to algorithm", which provide everything in details. Or [this](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=alg_index)

Comment: @user3129609 this approach can be considered a simple form of broader area which called dynamic programming.

Comment: Lol my bad i read the code wrong earlier, I know basic stuff about arrays and stuff. Guess learning dynamic programming, any book for that>?

Comment: @user3129609 Look at my comment earlier, should be enough for you to start :)